# Car freaks out on CANBUS shield connection

Tags: arduino-uno, can-bus

So, I'm trying to connect to my car's CAN-BUS (via the OBD2). I initially ordered a cheep shield then an even cheaper [module](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Arduino-CAN-BUS-Transceiver-Module-Car-OBD2-OBDII-MCP2515-16MHZ-Crystal-UK/253634327321?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) to provide connection between my uno and the car.

Using the module I was able to use some of the example libraries to successfully connect to the car and even get some IDs out. There was no data alongside the IDs so I figured my module needed upgrading.

I bought the [seeedstudio shield](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/143405678372) and used their libraries. At first I had the CANH and CANL connected into the car before starting it but that seems to have overwhelmed the car and I [couldn't start it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GX7YNonw9k), it behaved as if the battery was dead. 
Eventually when it recovered I tried again, this time the car was already running. Havig the CANL&H connected and the shield attached to the arduino and using the [example sketches](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield/tree/master/examples/gpioRead), when I provided power to the Arduino via the USB port the car started freaking out. The dials went crazy and started moving left to right and all sorts of warning messages started appearing on the dash - "check airbag", "engine motion something.." Disconnecting the shield from the car stops the freaking out and removes the errors displayed.

Any idea what's going on ?

Also should [any of these](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YRcp11EuGj1jZjYyfU1hojeEOPWZMTK9jFrJ4QQeqGJyIjDMWry5Q8XTZ8VWgeVXxhwWZi_Nj3ABbETgI2FA_y4RefQVAgGr-6_34RfRUmW0jD1dGrjkx32Dzs6hPHdIxv3ovqUKCD6etDjuk2H9k_nWIUsCDkyEVynKbzYSm9pWarBj8C9zOj96m4bgeViC8y30errdCGm2r-jrZOmEH6TxurNw6cW--T4v5aitECjzYquvFufEr1PksLn4LvHC_pNwEs5JusT6pxunxyRe5lvP_sD9_kIP7riVHc4ZLunyd_jINDApFOeaUGFvuFEywakXeKT9am12wMgq-GEKY2fxMe-Uvnv0V2e5WIOIIJET64CL8GsNM17YwWK654EZL0xbMW7_s9M3gyyamlTjZ0dmvbQghePQ6vvV3YhwAO7rSTV0s2wZSKjEw70VjurScDCrClMaeQkyekWH7JMXWpXPAvbDAcqLdeIC3mwqtDBRhUmrqEUXUW4nkZBo51T2NQKuV4KhQJile-U6Od64a3l_ZxD_Zop80RD3_AMVmU6fxfaMltjyikUg_jWP61f6490kdZqgjrc2C8sIdc3l_vB5OaeoCWvxssLeHDNfWLbyuOugO7-1RQHcpSuf67snleGFzbIrElLOy01RcgtMA9zzZsAUvn6wloCQvpl7V-a4Ha3XdCFTkEpyDHujlpI=w691-h921-no?authuser=0) be soldered to each other as the [manual](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/CAN-BUS_Shield_V2.0/) suggests there's some cutting and soldering there but I haven't cut nor soldered anything and this is how the shield arrived.

Worth pointing out that I tried connecting to both Pin6 as the proper CANH and also Pin1 as that one was discovered to also provide CANBUS data for the cabin. Here's the obd2 [diagram pinout](https://pinoutguide.com/CarElectronics/opel_obd2_diag_pinout.shtml) for my car.

Comment: This is old but for the sake of anyone who finds this. I cannot say for sure but Im pretty sure what you were seeing (gauges acting crazy) is due to your can card trying to communicate across the bus network at the same time as another moduL. If you were using this on an older car only one module “speaks” at any given time. Currently this is the same problem i am having which brought me to your post as i am trying to figure out which module in my car has a problem. My problem is so intermittent that back probing the individual modules doesnt help as the problem may only surface once every week

Comment: continuation of Shizzavip's answer converted to comment: ... or two. Gauges go wack. Either it will take care of itself after few minutes of driving or I can turn off and on and back to normal. So i am trying to build a arduino with canbus shield to just sniff so i can log to memory card and try and figure out which module is having problem.

Comment: You are lucky you did not damage your vehicle. The bus is not the same on all cars.